# ES6 composition. How to define some kind of getter

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I've written some code. I'm creating x1 object, and I want it to get everything using composition (not object inheritance). When it comes to variables, everything works perfect, but when I want to create method (It would be even better if there were possibility to make getter) it always returns same values, even when I change variables.

Code tells everything.
How to make it work the way I want to?

```
const CELLSIZE = 16;

const defaultObject = (state) => ({
    posx: state.posx,
    posy: state.posy,
    firstx: () => {
        return state.posx * CELLSIZE //???
    } 
})

const wall = (posx, posy)  => {
    let setup = {
        //Later there will be some not-inherited variables 
    }
    let state = {
        posx,
        posy,
    }
    return Object.assign(
        {},
        defaultObject(state),
        setup
    )
}

const x1 = wall(2, 5)

console.log(x1.firstx()) // Returns 32

x1.posx = 1

console.log(x1.firstx()) // Still returns 32, I want it to return 16
```

Comment: I added to my answer to address the getter thing.

Comment: I don't normally think of copying properties from one object to another as "composition." Having an object that has references to subordinate objects it uses to provide it's functionality (`wall` have a `defaultObject` it used, for instance), yes, but not copying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method is reading from the object you pass in as `state`:

```
const defaultObject = (state) => ({
    posx: state.posx,
    posy: state.posy,
    firstx: () => {
        return state.posx * CELLSIZE // <== Note you're reading from `state`
    } 
})
```

Instead, you want to read from the object you've created; but it's more complex than that, because although you're not using inheritance, you *are* copying things around, including copying that function from one object to another (via `Object.assign`). Because you're doing that, you can't use an arrow function for your `firstx` function; you have to use a normal function and rely on `this` being set correctly when it's called:

```
const defaultObject = (state) => ({
    posx: state.posx,
    posy: state.posy,
    firstx: function() {
        return this.posx * CELLSIZE; // <== Note reading from `this`
    } 
})
```

Live Example:

```js
const CELLSIZE = 16;

const defaultObject = (state) => ({
    posx: state.posx,
    posy: state.posy,
    firstx: function() {
        return this.posx * CELLSIZE; // <== Note reading from `this`
    } 
})

const wall = (posx, posy)  => {
    let setup = {
        //Later there will be some not-inherited variables 
    }
    let state = {
        posx,
        posy,
    }
    return Object.assign(
        {},
        defaultObject(state),
        setup
    )
}

const x1 = wall(2, 5)

console.log(x1.firstx()) // Returns 32

x1.posx = 1

console.log(x1.firstx()) // Returns 16
```

You can define `firstx` either with function notation (above), or method notation:

```
const defaultObject = (state) => ({
    posx: state.posx,
    posy: state.posy,
    firstx() {
        return this.posx * CELLSIZE; // <== Note reading from `this`
    } 
})
```

It doesn't matter which you use in this case, as you're not using `super` within `firstx`.

---

You said you wanted a getter; you can define a getter for that instead if you like:

```
const defaultObject = (state) => ({
    posx: state.posx,
    posy: state.posy,
    get firstx() {
        return this.posx * CELLSIZE; // <== Note reading from `this`
    } 
})
```

**but**, when you use `Object.assign`, it's going to read the *value* of that property and assign it to the new object, not the property descriptor defining the getter. You can copy that property descriptor over yourself later if you like, see `***` comments:

Live Example:

```js
const CELLSIZE = 16;

const defaultObject = (state) => ({
  posx: state.posx,
  posy: state.posy,
  get firstx() {                                          // ***
    return this.posx * CELLSIZE;                          // ***
  }                                                       // ***
})

const wall = (posx, posy) => {
  let setup = {
    //Later there will be some not-inherited variables 
  }
  let state = {
    posx,
    posy,
  }
  const original = defaultObject(state);                  // ***
  const obj = Object.assign({},
    original,                                             // ***
    setup
  )
  Object.defineProperty(                                  // ***
    obj,                                                  // ***
    "firstx",                                             // ***
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(original, "firstx")   // ***
  );                                                      // ***
  return obj;                                             // ***
}

const x1 = wall(2, 5)

console.log(x1.firstx) // Returns 32

x1.posx = 1

console.log(x1.firstx) // Returns 16
```

**However**, if you're not married to having `wall` make a copy of the object instead of augmenting it, [Oriol's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40960864/157247) changing how `wall` works is much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

`defaultObject` only has access to `state`. It creates an object with a `firstx` method which uses `state` data.

But then in `wall` you get that object, copy its properties, and throw it away.

When you modify the property at the end, `defaultObject` can't see that, because the `state` hasn't changed.

Instead, `wall` should return the same object returned by `defaultObject` (not a copy), and `defaultObject`'s methods should get the properties from the object it returns.

```js
const CELLSIZE = 16;

const defaultObject = (state) => {
  let obj = {
    posx: state.posx,
    posy: state.posy,
    firstx: () => {
      return obj.posx * CELLSIZE
    }
  };
  return obj;
};

const wall = (posx, posy)  => {
  let setup = {};
  let state = {posx, posy};
  return Object.assign(
    defaultObject(state),
    setup
  );
}

const x1 = wall(2, 5)
console.log(x1.firstx()) // Returns 32

x1.posx = 1
console.log(x1.firstx()) // Returns 16
```

Comment: Since it's an own method, my personal preference is not using `this` like in T.J.Crowder's answer. Consider using `this` with inheritance.

Comment: ...and doing the above makes using a getter much simpler (basically just change `firstx: () => {` to `get firstx() {`), because you're not copying the getter from one object to another. If changing the way `wall` works is an option, this is the way to do it.

Comment: One last question. Is there a possibility to for ex. overwrite defaultObject's methods? I thought, that `let setup` would such a thing, but again, I have no access to variables inside `let  obj`, If I wanted my method to return something different for particular objects (not created using wall)

Comment: @MuFFes: `defaultObject` returns a *new* object every time it's called. You can do what you like to that object, it won't affect either subsequent objects created by `defaultObject` or the values on your setup object.